Where does the Triforce design come from?
I'm a huge history nerd and saw the triforce symbol on a book about ancient Japan. Does anyone know the origins of it and original meaning behind the symbol?

While the triforce symbol is iconic to the Legend of Zelda game series, you seem to be asking this question from a more historical standpoint in real life versus anything about the game - which means I don't think this is on-topic for our site.  It would maybe be better suited on History SE.

Procedurally casting close vote per Timmy Jim's comment.

According to Wikipedia,

Although the Triforce has become associated with The Legend of Zelda
series, an identical symbol originated nearly 1,000 years before in
medieval Japan. The symbol takes historical reference from the Hōjō
clan, a family that took control of Japan in the 13th century. Its
emblem (mon) was the mitsuuroko, or "three scales". The symbol also
appears frequently in contemporary Japanese culture. It appears on the
logos for large and small businesses and can be found on temples and
family memorials. Since the release of The Legend of Zelda video game
in 1986, the Triforce has become a recognisable icon of The Legend of
Zelda series, appearing in every game in some form, particularly as
part of the heraldry of the Kingdom of Hyrule.

It also went through multiple iterations, even in different games. The article also mentions,

Shigeru Miyamoto, creator of The Legend of Zelda series, explained his
vision for the first game in an interview with Gamekult. He said that
the Triforce fragments were originally supposed to be electronic
chips, as the game was intended to be set in both the past and the
future. This early futuristic concept was abandoned and replaced by a
heroic fantasy.In The Legend of Zelda video game, the Triforce was
simply described as magical triangles of great power, but its
significance was expanded in subsequent games. The first game
established it as an object of desire and a central plot device that
binds the three characters. Initially comprising two pieces, the third
piece, the Triforce of Courage, was introduced in Zelda II: The
Adventure Of Link.


Will always find it funny that this old concept is why the protagonist is Link. He was supposed to be the Link between the 2 worlds.
